# SOQL Out side For loop

Tags: trigger

I have written this trigger and it is working but I want to remove my query from for loop

```
trigger BlockDoublebooking on Session_Speaker__c (before insert) {
//Set<Id> SessionSpeakerIds=new Set<Id>();
 List<Session_Speaker_> ss2;
for(Session_Speaker__c newrec:trigger.new){
   ss2=[select Id from Session_Speaker__c where Session__c=:newrec.Session__c and Speaker__c=:newrec.Speaker__c];
   if(!ss2.isEmpty()){
    newrec.addError('REject double booking');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maps are your best friend here .

I have revised the code

```
trigger BlockDoublebooking on Session_Speaker__c (before insert) {

Set<Id> SessionSpeakerIds=new Set<Id>();
set<Id> SessionIds = new set<Id>();
map<String,Session_Speaker__c> mapkeyBySessionSpeaker = new map<String,Session_Speaker__c>();//This map will hold Session Speaker record in database for combination of Speaker and Session Id

for(Session_Speaker__c newrec:trigger.new){
  if(newrec.Speaker__c != null){
     SessionSpeakerIds.add(newrec.Speaker__c);
  }
  if(newrec.Session__c != null){
     SessionIds.add(newrec.Session__c);
  }
}

for(Session_Speaker__c sSpeaker :[select Id,Session__c,Speaker__c from Session_Speaker__c where Session__c IN :SessionIds and Speaker__c IN :SessionSpeakerIds]){
   mapkeyBySessionSpeaker.put(sSpeaker.Session__c+sSpeaker.Speaker__c,sSpeaker);
}

for(Session_Speaker__c newrec:trigger.new){
    if(mapkeyBySessionSpeaker.get(newrec.Session__c+newrec.Speaker__c) != null){
        newrec.addError('REject double booking');
    }
}

}
```

Comment: It might not be worth writing the code to check this, but, given the OP's working definition of "double booking", it's technically possible that the records in `trigger.new` may contain double bookings as well. This check could be done in the first for loop by building a `Map<Id, Set<Id>>` (map key is `Speaker__c`, set is of `Session__c` Ids). If, in building this collection, a given map key's set already contains the current iteration's `Session__c`, we know that `trigger.new` contains a double booking.

Comment: @DerekF I see your point .The incoming stream may have duplicates as well but I was trying to explain the user how  to take queries out of loop and was not addressing any business requirement here .